# How to complete the code to take the input as an integer and output a square of "*" characters

Tags: python

```
val = int(input())
for x in range (0, val):
    print('*',end='')
```

I want to get the answer input is 5 when

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

How to do this???

Comment: `print('*'*val)`

Comment: `for _ in range(val): print('*' * val)`

Comment: `print( * ['*' * val] * val, sep='\n' )`

Comment: Thanks guys print('*' * val) is correct 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a bit weird, you can actually multiply your string by a number, and it will print the string that many times.

```
val = int(input())
for x in range (0, val):
    print('*' * val)
```